# class design improvement - user validation

Tags: php

I'm looking to improve this class - any suggestions?  It checks for empty, name, email, and password.
The regex for email is very simple.  A very lengthy article from the Linux Journal for improving upon this is [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585).  The character set for password I borrowed from the NASA signup page.  For name I allow letters, periods, and dashes.  Testing for empty was developed with in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464515/testing-an-array-for-an-empty-string-and-returning-an-int-0-or-1-best-practic)

```
class check 
  {
  static function empty_user($a)
    {
    return (int)!in_array('',$a,TRUE); 
    }
  static function name($a)          
    {
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z-\.]{1,40}$/',$a);
    }
  static function email($a)
    {
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._s-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$/',$a);
    }
  static function pass($a)
    {
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,20}$/',$a);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use a regex to validate email addresses.  Also, why is this in a class?  A namespace would make more sense.

Comment: For email validation/sanitization look at the built in (PHP 5.2+) filter functions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php

Comment: is it possible to see the regex they use for the filters?

Comment: @Chris Aaker Good question. This link answers that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682106/how-are-phps-built-in-functions-implemented-internally/5682120#5682120

Comment: Please don't edit the question to make the existing answers meaningless. If you have new versions of the code post a new question. Reference this one (in it's original form) and explain that it's a new issue.
 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94446/editing-a-question-and-asking-a-completely-different-question
 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/rolling-back-a-completely-changed-question

Comment: As @palacsint said: Please stop editing your questions to something unrelated. If you keep doing this, you'll be suspended.

Comment: To add to the previous, you may want to consider some more cases for the name. Apostrophes are a good idea to cater for Irish names, as well as allowing a single whitespace (for people with a von or a de in their names, such as yours truly). A better regex: /^[a-zA-Z-\'\.(\s?)]{1,40}$/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as mentioned by @user7212, use php `filter_var()` for email validation. Please see below for example:

```
/**
 * Validate email
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public static function email($email)
{
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Second, why not naming your function params? If the email validation function would be called `$email`, if would be much easier to understand then `$a`.

`in_array()` function, according to it's [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php), returns `bool`. Why converting it to `int`? The result of the check should be `bool`.

In the `pass()` function, are you checking a string or a hash? Which brings us to the following item - write comments for your code! [PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) is a good example on how to do that.

And the last, but not the least - the name of the class. `Check` is not the most appropriate name. I would consider `Validation` or `Valid`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please tick the answer if it helped ;)